# Need Help.. Picture uploader function for windows mobile 6 net cf 3.5

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

all runs perfect but the thing that cost me my last nervs is the getstring part .. 
that function is wonderfull but i need a way to find an alternative for the getstring problem.. 
with getstring(pic,0,pic.length) i became an error.. and find no way out big thx for help

hers the code:

```
Public Function uploadPic(ByVal pic As Byte(), ByVal filename As String, ByVal user As String)
    Dim encoding As String = "iso-8859-1"
    'Erzeugen einer einzigartigen identifikation
    Dim gui As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    'Diese wird für den Header und den footer der Daten benötigt
    Dim head As String = String.Format("--{0}", gui)
    Dim foot As String = String.Format("--{0}--", gui)
    'Einen Stringbuilder erstellen, in dem wir nun bequem die
    'benötigten POST Daten speichern können
    Dim contents As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    'Benutzerdaten schreiben (benutzername)
    contents.AppendLine(head)
    contents.AppendLine(String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""", "username"))
    contents.AppendLine()
    contents.AppendLine(user)
    'Header schreiben
    contents.AppendLine(head)
    'Bildinformationen schreiben, Bildkopf und die Binärdaten
    Dim fileHeader As String = String.Format("Content-Disposition: file; name=""{0}""; filename=""{1}""", "media", user & ".jpg")
    Dim fileData As String = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetString(pic)
    'Informationen zu dem Übergebenen Dateityp schreiben
    contents.AppendLine(fileHeader)
    contents.AppendLine(String.Format("Content-Type: {0}", "image/jpeg"))
    contents.AppendLine()
    contents.AppendLine(fileData)
    'Durch schreiben des footers signalisieren dass keine Daten mehr kommen
    contents.AppendLine(foot)
    'MessageBox.Show(contents.ToString)
    'Stream Reader zum lesen der Antwort von Twitpic
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim result As String
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse
    'Einen Webrequest zu der TwitPic API erstellen
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://urspacecity.de/uploadpic/up.php")
    request.ContentType = String.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", gui)
    request.Method = "POST"
    'Die Daten die noch im Stringbuilder als String vorliegen
    'in das byte (Binär)-Format umwandeln, damit die API diese annimt
    Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetBytes(contents.ToString())
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    'Einen Stream aus dem WebRequest erstellen
    Dim writer As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    'Die Binären Daten in den Strom schreiben
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    response = request.GetResponse()
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    result = reader.ReadToEnd
    reader.Close()

    Return result
End Function
```

Finally found the solution -- change the encoding:

```
Dim encoding As String = "iso-8859-2"
```

Comment: Please specify the problem or the exception received.

Comment: the error with getstring(pic,0,pic.length) is 

PlatformNotSupportedException

screenshoot:
http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/6143/bild20100827174500.png

and with getstring(pic) see screenshoot:
http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/2611/bild20100827174645.png

on pc it runs perfect but on compact framework 3.5 i found no way to fix it up. the readallbytes problem is fixed but now i hang on that prob.

Comment: ok now i have big eyes .. i seen an articel and tryed the iso-8859-2.. now he make no trouble at the getstring .. but now he stops at response = request.getresponse() -.- with error : 
{"The response for this request cannot be retrieved until request data has been written."}

Answer (score 2):

To solve "the response for this request cannot be retrieved until request data has been written" error, you should close the `writer` stream before calling `request.GetResponse()`, like this:

```
writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
writer.Close()
response = request.GetResponse()
```

You don't have to do this in desktop version of .net but you have to in .net compact framework.

I know this is an old question, and my answer is likely be ignored by asker but "the response for this request cannot be retrieved until request data has been written" google search directed me to this question. I hope it helps someone.